# How can I choose several values at once in data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

```
df[(df["Variable"]=="% Recycling") & (df["Country"]== ["United Kingdom", "Türkiye", "OECD - Total"])]
```

I could not understand why would this code give errors.

Comment: The code is throwing error due to this condition `df["Country"]== ["United Kingdom", "Türkiye", "OECD - Total"]`. In `Country` column there is no values which equals `["United Kingdom", "Türkiye", "OECD - Total"]`. So, `==` will not work but `isin` or `contains` will work.

Answer (score 2):

Try `isin`; you also need `.loc`:

```
df.loc[df["Variable"].eq("% Recycling") 
   & df["Country"].isin(["United Kingdom", "Türkiye", "OECD - Total"])]
```

or try with `query`:

```
df.query("Variable == '% Recycling' and Country in ['United Kingdom', 'Türkiye', 'OECD - Total']")
```